# Storing Multiple Models in Loop and save these to compare Variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

I'm interested in using RandomForest as my model for a classification problem. I have been able to run a very simple model for initial testing. However, I want to try a nested loop to run various models and save these to a vector. This is to achieve two principal objectives:

1. To extract the best model of these from my loop (or maybe get an average of these models?)
2. To compare the most important variables between my models and see which are the most commonly top selected features per prediction.

I am currently testing with the Iris dataset to see how feasible this is before applying on a larger dataset with many more features (> 100)

### Nested Model Example

What I have so far is the following:

```
#Set Control
myControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)

#Set a counter
myCounter <- 0

RFModel_Vector <- c()

#Nested Loop to select best model
for (i in 0:2)
{
    # Train a default Random Forest Model
    RFModel_Vector <- randomForest(y = factor(iris$Species), 
                         x = iris[, colnames(iris) != "Species"],
                         importance = TRUE,
                         proximity = TRUE, 
                         trControl = myControl,
                         metric = "Accuracy",
                         ntree = 100)
    # Count Number of Loops
    myCounter = counter + 1
    print (myCounter)
}
```

I have also seen that there is a function `caretList` that can be used for ensemble methods.

I'm not entirely sure on how to go about this. Any help?

Comment: The Boruta R package does feature selection with random forest.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `list` to store the output as model output objects are `list` themselves and it is better to store it in a `list`

```
RFModel_Vector <- vector('list', 3)
for (i in seq_along(RFModel_Vector))
{
    # Train a default Random Forest Model
    RFModel_Vector[[i]] <- randomForest(y = factor(iris$Species), 
                         x = iris[, colnames(iris) != "Species"],
                         importance = TRUE,
                         proximity = TRUE, 
                         trControl = myControl,
                         metric = "Accuracy",
                         ntree = 100)
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Sorry for the late response. I can access each separate model in the list I believe then and extract the most important variables for comparison? :)